# InternalsVisibleTo is not working in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I use InternalsVisibleTo in my MVC project to access internal class no problem, but in Razor Pages it no work. What I do wrong?

If I remove reference to internal class from razor page and build, I can see two dll created. MyProject.dll and MyProject.Views.dll.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Views")]
```

So this Class attribute should work no? It work in MVC project but why no Razor Pages project?

Comment: Why not make them public? The view is another part of your program, there is no reason why it should be able to access the internals.

Comment: But why it work in MVC but no Razor Pages? Is bug or something?

Comment: Found a similar question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264992/using-internal-properties-in-razorengine/42355462