# Making a C# project inaccessible to a single project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a VS2022 solution with 20 c# projects, .NET 4.8.1, with the main project being an MVC 5 web application. One of the classes in class library handles session information.  I want to make this class Internal and only use it in the main web project.

So I made the class internal and added

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Myapplication.Web")]
```

which is the assembly name to the web project. Ok, all is good there and the properties in that class are accessible.

However, the properties are NOT available in the Razor pages, and I get the

```
'Classname' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Since cshtml files are compiled into the temporary internet files with essentially random assembly names, how can I accomplish this? Is there a way to make an internal class visible to a specific csproj rather than assembly, or compile the cshtml into the main web assembly to begin with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264992/using-internal-properties-in-razorengine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867547/internalsvisibleto-is-not-working-in-razor-pages - short version: "nope"

Comment: Saw those earlier, thought there might be a way to do it with the current c# version. Thanks.

Comment: Can you move the code of the class library into the web application project?

Comment: No, because another class project uses it.